# Kitchen Cabinets Turning Orange

Tags: kitchens, cabinets

I used Howard’s Wood Polish and Conditioner to clean some grime but it seems to have turned the portion I cleaned orange possibly stripping the initial layer of color

I wanted to see what folks recommended that don’t involve a lot of effort to fix.

[image: cabinets]